# I have never seen this "Sign in..." message before downloading

Tags: ios, itunes, icloud, ios-appstore, password

[image: Image of message "Sign In...]
I Am wondering why I am getting the message [above] all of the sudden. As far as I know I am already signed in. Why is this message being displayed, rather than the one similar to the one in the 2nd image: 
[image: Message to enter Apple ID password]
Have I been hacked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a normal App Store pop-up. It does mean that somehow you were logged out of your Apple ID on your phone though, which could be for any number of reasons. Maybe someone signed out on your phone or someone tried to hack into your account and Apple forced all devices to re-authenticate, but there isn't an easy way to find out.

Comment: If I am getting this message should I be worried, in the case that someone is trying to hack?

Comment: You should probably make sure your security is up-to-date. That means using a secure password that you don't use anywhere else and using 2-step authentication. However, this doesn't mean anything is necessarily wrong with your account.

Comment: Ok, but if someone has gotten this far in attempting a hack, how much access would they have?

Comment: There is no evidence that anyone succeeded in a hack (yet). If they did, your email or password probably would have been changed or purchases would have been made. If someone was indeed attempting to hack you (which I doubt, but you never know), then just follow the steps in my previous comment and you'll be fine.